# Google glass and Video/Photo Upload code sample

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Is there a code sample to upload Video or Photo to a server. I see CNN has iReport and Dubai Police has a way to upload media. I want to upload to a secure place where only a private group of folks can see the uploaded media. (May be a private google hangout or box or dropbox)

I see the documentation. Little confused. Hence the question.
https://developers.google.com/glass/media-upload#simple

Also, Is there code sample to download a media and play from box or private google hangout

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you dont need anything particular for google glass as long as it supports android 4.4.4

You can either implement your own [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class and [example of usage](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/android-image-upload-activity/).

but I use third party libraries, since they are tested and more reliable with additional fancy functionality I would not implement otherwise. My favorite is http://square.github.io/okhttp/ , they have good documentation and examples on how to use it for android.